# How do I execute my custom submission handler before any other submission handler?

Tags: forms

I want to execute my custom submission handler for a button before any other submission handler associated with that button. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should add it at the first position in handlers array.

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'] = array_merge( array('your_form_submit'), $form['actions']['submit']['#submit']);
```

Answer (score 2):

[array_unshift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) the name of the function onto the "#submit" array of the button.

Comment: This is valid also for `$form['#submit']` for which the code is similar to `array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'mymodule_form_submit')`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Me thinks this would affect all buttons on the form.

Comment: I know; I was pointing out to who reads that the same code can be used with `$form['#submit']`, not that in this case the code should alter both the buttons' submission handler and the form submission handler.